# Which is better, or is it simply for presentation?

Tags: java

Is there a difference between this:

```
 if (!something) {
   // do something
   return true;
 }
```

And this:

```
if (something) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else here
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first code snippet say `do something else here`?

Comment: Your snippets dont match logic wise, there is no use comparing them

Comment: Your question has no answer.  Depending on what you need to do with the code, either answer is correct, or neither is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean, which is better for readability, this:

```
if (condition) {
   // do something
   return true;
}

// do something else
return false;
```

Or this:

```
if (condition) {
   // do something
   return true;
} else {
   // do something else
   return false;
}
```

Definitely the first one is better for readability.

Logically, they're equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer to clarify this. I've received a lot of stick for this question even though I'm fairly new but I'm glad you have helped.